# What to return after login via API?

Tags: laravel, api, oauth-2.0, jwt, laravel-passport

I'm creating an API server which will be consumed by a mobile app that I will work on later. I have yet to see any reference of API best practices related to user flow and returned data even after searching for several hours.

My question is whether the login response of an API should return the a personal access token with the refresh token along with the user info? Or should I just return the token and make another API call for getting the user info.

I could just do what I have in mind but I'm trying to learn the best practices so that I don't have to adjust a lot of things later.

I need suggestions as well as good references related to my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are using for your authentication. If you are using libraries like **Laravel Passport** or **JWT**, you can have the token endpoint which returns the access token, refresh token, validity period and the token type (Bearer). You can then have an authenticated endpoint which will be used to get a user's profile based of the token passed in the request header.

However, if you go through the documentation for those libraries, in most there is an allowance to **manually generate** a token. You can use this in a custom endpoint that will return the token as well as the user profile [Passport Manually Generate Token](https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-with-passport-of-laravel-5-6-1dc2d400a7f).

If you are using JWT, you can also embed a few user properties in the token itself. The client can the get the profile info from the JWT itself without having to make a round trip to the server. [Passport ADD Profile to JWT](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/94#issuecomment-374097833)

If you have a custom way in which you are handling authentication, you can pass the token as well as the user profile in the same response.

In the end, it's up to you to decide what suits you best.

Comment: I have read somewhere that password grant is better for first-party clients (which in this case the API owner also owns the Mobile App). So I might stick to that. I'm just figuring out why guzzle doesn't work when posting to /oauth/token. Anyway, is there a pro to why I should issue personal access token rather than password grant? I was required to reduce token lifetime so I guess personal access token with long lifetime is not going to happen.

Comment: Personally I would avoid using personal access tokens for mobile app authentication. Go for password grant type. However, I would "proxy" the token endpoint so that the clients don't have the secret for password grant.


You should read up on the different flows and their use cases.

Comment: There is a config for token duration in the documentation. For your guzzle issue try this [Guzzle Proxy](https://gist.github.com/NimzyMaina/1cc527997ffdf576314f8a7aa133bcb7)

Comment: I have figured out that guzzle does not if ports are defined in the link. Something like 192.168.1.2:8000 will not work. So I decided to use laravel valet so that ports wont be included in the link, and it worked.

Comment: And as of date, I have decided to just return what /oauth/token returns. I might change it to also return other user details once I start working on the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at OpenID Connect?  It's another layer on top of OAuth 2.0 and provides user authentication (OAuth 2.0 does not cover authentication, it just assumes it happens) and ways to find information about the current user.
It has the concept of an ID_token, in addition to the OAuth access token, and also provides a /userinfo endpoint to retrieve information about the user.
You **could** put user information in your access token, but security best practice is to NOT allow your access token to be accessible from JavaScript (i.e. use HTTP_ONLY cookies to store your access token).

Comment: The client has talked about Google's apigee. Will that be a possible alternative for OpenID connect? I have not yet researched about that but I will once I have finished some other requirements.